# Is there a way to know if the found boost libraries are static or dynamic?

Tags: boost, cmake

Is there a way to know if libraries returned from `FindPackage(Boost)` are the static or the dynamic alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` variable to control which type of files is looked for by `find_library` commands. This is also utilized by the FindBoost module. Then you can call `find_package` twice to detect if the desired static or shared version is available.
Two things I haven't checked yet (but will do): First, It could be that the find module for boost sets it's own suffixes for the time being run. Second, cmake could automatically set appropriate suffixes depending on the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` flag; in that case you'll automatically get *only* a library of the same type returned, if found.